# How to retrieve all items under html5 <nav> tag

Tags: jquery, html

Mark-up:

```
<nav id="gallery">
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_1.jpg" id="1"/></a>
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_2.jpg" id="2" /></a>
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_3.jpg" id="3"/></a>
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_4.jpg" id="4"/></a>
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_5.jpg" id="5"/></a>
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_6.jpg" id="6"/></a>
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_7.jpg" id="7"/></a>
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_8.jpg" id="8"/></a>
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_9.jpg" id="9"/></a>
    <a><img src="images/ThumbImages/thumb_10.jpg" id="10"/></a>
</nav>
```

Trying to retrieve like this :

jQuery :

```
var elem = $("#gallery");
```

But, during debugging it says that the elem length is 1.

How do I retrieve all the images in `elem`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following code:

```
var elemImgs = $("#gallery img");
```

`$('#gallery')` only has a length of 1 because you specifically asked for the `#gallery` node itself and not it's children.

Answer (score 4):

With:

```
var elem = $("#gallery img");
```

will give you all images inside element with id `gallery`.

---

You can use `each()` to iterate over all images also:

```
elem.each(function(){
  // do something with each image
});
```

---

Have a [look at documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to learn more about selectors if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("nav#gallery  a").each(function(){
  // anchor text
    console.log($(this).text());
  // image src
    console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```